# Regression of a ratio of two continuous variables (i.e. regressing continuous proportions)

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, ratio

I have data of the following form:

```
    Plot Year    BiomAll   BiomPITA     Ratio
       4 1933   9.704257   9.701901 0.9997572
       4 2013 379.425369 326.964477 0.8617359
      14 1933   4.899774   4.899774 1.0000000
      14 2013 174.968471 115.312454 0.6590470
      ....
```

where `BiomAll` is total plot biomass of a forest stand, `BiomPITA` is the amount of biomass from one species (PITA), and `Ratio` is the ratio of PITA biomass to total stand biomass for the given `Plot`-`Year` combo.

I want to know: **Has the ratio of PITA biomass in forest stands decreased with time? (and at what rate?)**

The dependent variable, `Ratio`, is constructed from continuous variables but is bounded by 1 and 0.

Most sources I see construct ratios from counts or binary data. However, the `Ratio` in my data does not come from count nor binary data.

**So I'm unsure of how to set up my model.**

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/303592/80624) seems to suggest to me that I should use a `binomial` distribution, but [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232979/logistic-regression-use-of-real-values-between-0-and-1as-opposed-to-two-clas/233003#233003) makes me think my data does *not* apply to using logistic regression.

The logistic model:

```
glmer(Ratio ~ I(Year-1970) + (1 + I(Year - 1970) | Plot), family = binomial, data = dat)
```

Can anyone help confirm for me what model to use (and how to set this up in R using `glmer`?

---

**Update**:

[This source](http://support.sas.com/kb/57/480.html) claims:

> While the binomial distribution is generally applicable to a dependent (response) variable that represents proportions from aggregated binary responses, it might not apply to underlying continuous data.
>
> Response measurements, like those above, that are...percentages of a total amount...might not be binomial since they do not represent a set of independent trials.
>
> When the response in a regression model is a proportion or a percentage, it can be **difficult to decide on an appropriate modeling approach**. While **some researchers use the simplest approach and fit a linear regression model**, ordinary linear regression can predict invalid values that are less than zero or greater than one

Both [that site](http://support.sas.com/kb/57/480.html) and [this site](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/proportions-as-dependent-variable-in-regression-which-type-of-model/) claim that moving forward with a linear model is fine if the majority of data "fall in the middle of the range (between about 0.3 and 0.7)."

Alas, my data do not:

[image]

[This source](http://support.sas.com/kb/57/480.html) suggests 2 alternatives using SAS:

> Two ways to model continuous proportions include using the beta distribution in the GLIMMIX procedure or defining a nonlinear model using the NLIN or NLMIXED procedures in SAS/STAT® software.

Can I use either of these approaches in R?

- **Update:** [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/231980/80624) attempts to recreate GLIMMIX in R using `glmer` with a `binomial` distribution and `weight` argument.

  - However, when I try this approach I get a warning:

    ```
     glmer(Ratio ~ I(Year-1970) + (1 + I(Year - 1970) | Plot), family = binomial, data = bds, weights = BiomAll, glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
     Warning Message
     In eval(family$initialize, rho) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
    ```

Is there still a simpler way to go about this? (e.g., see my comment below).

Comment: Is it better to just split the ratio and use `BiomPITA` as a dependent variable and use `BiomAll` as an independent variable in a normal inear model?? If so, How would I translate that back to a ratio to answer my question?

Comment: Your data might benefit from a suitable transformation: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=CLR+ILR.

Comment: @theforestecologist for continuous proportions some people consider beta regression; we have a number of questions on site with answers discussing it.